# Is "action withheld" correct?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In a formal environment, is it correct to say, for example, "action withheld due to insufficient information" to mean that you decided not to take action for that reason?

Information and payment are among the words that are more commonly used with the verb withhold. I'm not sure if "action is withheld" or "action withheld" sounds natural or rather forced.

Answer (score 2):

To me "action (is) withheld" is perfectly understandable, but sounds odd both with and without the "is". It would be more common to say in a note "no action taken due to insufficient information", or more formally "No action was taken due to insufficient information being provided."